# How would I add a fadein function to this script using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I'm using the script below to change a background image on click, but I'd like the transition to be a bit smoother with a fadein. Would that be possible?

Here is the script:

```
      <script>
  $(function(){
      $("#button").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.class').css("background-image", "url('http://website.com/images/image.png')");

      });
      });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fadeOut the `.class` element first and use the callback function to change the css and  to fadeIn again....

```
  <script>
 $(function(){
    $("#button").on("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.class').fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(this).css("background-image", "url('http://website.com/images/image.png')").fadeIn('slow');
      })

    });
 });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will give you a nice fadeIn effect.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
      $("#button").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.class').fadeIn(800).css("background-image", "url('http://website.com/images/image.png')");

      });
      });
</script>
```